# Docker error: HTTP 408 response body: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value

Tags: docker

When I go `docker pull hello-world` I get the below error message:

`Error response from daemon: error parsing HTTP 408 response body: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value: "<html><body><h1>408 Request Time-out</h1>\nYour browser didn't send a complete request in time.\n</body></html>\n\n"`

Installed Docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:      1.11.2
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   b9f10c9
 Built:        Wed Jun  1 21:47:50 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.11.2
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   b9f10c9
 Built:        Wed Jun  1 21:47:50 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Installed using: `curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh`

I have ensured that network exists and I can reach other sites. Please help

Update 1: The issue cannot be of setting MTU because I could pull the images from Docker hub a few days back on the same machine.

The issue cannot be of HTTP_PROXY either because I am in my home network

Comment: Seems a bit odd but try looking at this github issue: [timeouts pulling images](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20628). Describes same error, and some using Docker v1.11.x (MTU issue). You could also try installing 1.12rc version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is little misleading. The problem was not that there was invalid character, but the network was misconfigured. I had one LAN interface and one WLAN interface.

LAN interface connects to a router A which forward requests to router B which was connected to internet. While the WLAN interface was directly connected to router B. I forgot to remove the WLAN configuration.

Once I ensured the WLAN interface is removed, things worked smoothly.

In short: Ensured DNS resolution works and that MTU is set right.

**Another possible reason for error**

If you are using Mac, please ensure to allow Unrestriction Access to Web Content like below:

[image]

**Another possible step in troubleshooting**

Ensure there is no proxy or web filter in your network, that is, if possible connect to your 3G network and try again to see if the results are different

Comment: Exactly! I just got the same error when I have two network interfaces with different settings. After I close one interface the problem is solved!

Comment: hi i am facing this issue for my own private repo on dockerhub. when i try `docker pull username/repo:tag` it gives me `repo does not exist or requires docker login` error, and when I try `docker pull hub.docker.com/username/repo:tag` it gives me the `error parsing HTTP 404 response body` error. I am successfully logged into the docker CLI. Am I missing a step?

Comment: Are you using Mac or Linux @SpencerTrinh ?

Comment: hi @Romaan, I developed on macosx and pushed from it too. But for work I am using Win10 with Docker Desktop (WSL). This is the laptop that I can't pull from. It seems to pull fine from the Mac osx though. Does it have to do anything with proxies? I saw some threads that mention this, but no written solution on what to do

Comment: @Romaan Thanks your fix for mac worked. I don't understand what it's doing though. Can you explain what it did?

Comment: Mac filters the traffic @junecng and it blocks and sends an error with its page. And then docker does not expect that response, so it throws up error in turn

Answer (score 20):

I have run across this issue a couple times with Raspberry Pi boards running various flavors of Debian/Raspbian (RPi model info was obtained by `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep Model`):

- `Raspberry Pi Model B Rev 1` with Raspbian based on Debian 11 (bullseye)
- `Raspberry Pi 4 MOdel B Rev 1.4` with Debian 10 (buster)

In both cases, running `docker run --rm hello-world` resulted in the `408` HTTP status code reported in the original question in this thread:

```bash
$ docker run --rm hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: error parsing 
HTTP 408 response body: invalid character '<' 
looking for beginning of value: "<html><body>
<h1>408 Request Time-out</h1>\nYour browser 
didn't send a complete request in time.\n</body>
</html>\n".
See 'docker run --help'.
```

The solution (noted as an [aside](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38940404/5299483) by [@Romaan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1707750/romaan)) was to adjust the MTU.  I did this as follows:

```bash
sudo ip link set dev eth0 mtu 1400
docker run --rm hello-world
```

and the `hello-world` container was successfully pulled and executed.

Examples of how to permanently adjust the MTU for a network interface on Debian may be found [here](https://www.debianhelp.co.uk/mtu.htm).

Comment: I confirm in my similar case it was MTU size (1400) due to LTE (4G) mobile operator network setup.
Although also I had to switch my OpenVPN that I also use from UDP to TCP to get it completely resolved due to poor network quality.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was trying to set the MTU, and was wondering how large could I set it, found this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/590608/534619. Though sadly even if I set the MTU to the largest possible value, I still see the 408 error. Have to keep digging.

Comment: @MadHatter, I think your issue is that there is something else that has a smaller MTU on the network, and so your packets aren't getting through.  You want to set the MTU _smaller_, not to the largest possible value because at one of the other hops on your network I suspect you're exceeding the MTU of that node (once the data is wrapped in TCP headers). Try something like 1300 and see if that resolves the 408 status code; then you can try to find the upper bound on what will work.  Use 1300 to diagnose whether or not this is an MTU issue.

Comment: @LemonCat, thanks a lot for your info. Earlier I was using the docker save/docker load to bypass the issue. Whenever there was a successful build, I save the docker image and upload to our internal server, then at somewhere else download the image and load it.
I will try your suggestion when I get some time to test. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

That error message looks like it's coming from a proxy server. From the [docker pull documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/)

> Proxy configuration
>
> If you are behind an HTTP proxy server, for example in corporate
>   settings, before open a connect to registry, you may need to configure
>   the Docker daemon’s proxy settings, using the HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY,
>   and NO_PROXY environment variables. To set these environment variables
>   on a host using systemd, refer to the control and configure Docker
>   with systemd for variables configuration.

The link to the [instructions for configuring systemd with a proxy](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/#http-proxy) is straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

It's really internet connection. Change MTU.

```
ip link set dev [interface] mtu [size]
ip enp1s0 mtu 1000 up
```

You can get your device info using

```
ip a
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem on Ubuntu. I managed to solve it by disconnecting from NordVPN:

```
$ nordvpn disconnect
You are disconnected from NordVPN.
```

It seems the VPN somehow slowed down the dockerhub traffic and broke my docker pulls.

Answer (score 0):

There is a high chance that this is caused due to internet connectivity issue, try to rerun when the internet connection is stable.

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved after decreasing the mtu to 900 by the below command.

```
ip link set dev [interface] mtu [size]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you are in some restricted area just setup a  vpn to bypass filter (country like iran, ...) or use service like shecan

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using docker on a fresh install of Ubuntu Server LTS.

Initially, I was reluctant to just randomly play with changing MTU size since I've installed a bunch of packaged from apt-get and even pulled a docker image from ghcr.io.

In the end, the problem was indeed MTU, and it was causing issues with uplink, while downlink was fine - that's why I could fetch other stuff, but docker.io was timing out.

You can verify if this is also a problem by running a speed test on the affected machine, especially if it is a Raspberry Pi. You can install speed test by Ookla here: https://www.speedtest.net/apps/cli