# Pulling docker images from private repo within a corporate network

Tags: docker, proxy, container-registry, docker-pull

I am trying to pull a docker image from a private repo within the corporate network:

`docker pull <IP:PORT>/sample-service`

```
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from sample-service
4fe2ade4980d: Pulling fs layer
6fc58a8d4ae5: Pulling fs layer
819f4a45746e: Pulling fs layer
16ff43210df7: Waiting
```

Have already logged in successfully and I

I have removed the proxy setting since it was interfering with pulling from the private repo with `Error response from daemon: error unmarshalling content: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value`, although I had set `NO_PROXY` before and was working with k8s without issues.

---

> 1. What are the http_proxy and no_proxy settings I should have for this? I followed [this doc](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/) with my corresponding proxy URL.
> 2. Can I set NO_PROXY with a file like http-proxy.conf ??? How best to set multiple NO_PROXY IPs?

---

Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38386809/docker-error-http-408-response-body-invalid-character-looking-for-beginnin) has anything with my issue? How to check if this is a DNS issue related to an interface?