# Can't pull docker image

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerhub, multipass

[image]I have encountered a problem that I hope someone can help me with. I am using multipass on macos to run docker swarm, but I get an error when I try to pull an image (see attached picture). Does anyone have a solution or a suggestion for this issue? Thank you in advance.

I tried to pull docker image inside ubuntu virtual machine (multipass) with docker preinstalled.

text from picture:

```
ubuntu@promising-pilchard:~$ docker pull redis
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: error parsing HTTP 408 response body: 
invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value: "<html>. 
<body><h1>408 Request Time-out</h1>\nYour browser didn't send a 
complete request in time.\n</body></html>\n"
```

Comment: `see attached picture` No picture is attached. Instead of attaching a picture, can you copy/paste the error? It improves searchability.

Comment: sure, I updated the question sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38386809/docker-error-http-408-response-body-invalid-character-looking-for-beginnin) suggests the problem may be that your MTU is set too high.

Comment: I appreciate your help very much. I had overlooked the solution you gave because it was not marked as the correct one. It turns out that it was exactly what I needed. How ironic that I wasted so much time searching for something that was right in front of me.